# Data on building locations and characteristic in France

Tags: data-request, geospatial, france

I am looking for data on French buildings on an address level, e.g. elevation, height, number of floors, square meters, type of building etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map of Orange County (CA) buildings](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/map-of-orange-county-ca-buildings)

Answer (score 3):

Buidings are available for Paris on the city opendata portal (with some wanted properties). Have a look on the following link :

https://parisdata.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/volumesbatisparis2011/

From what I know, you will not be able to find a dataset on the whole France. OSM data could be interesting locally but not at such scale.

You may explore some other cities opendata plateforms.